# Create an order-by Expression<Func<T>> with multiple fields

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

How do I create an order-by expression that involves multiple fields?

This isn't the correct syntax:

```
Expression<Func<Employee, Object>> orderByExpression = null;
orderByExpression = e => e.LastName || e.FirstName;

_service.GetEmployeesAsync(orderByExpression);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that names are strings this should work:

```
orderByExpression = e => e.LastName + e.FirstName;
```

But common pattern for ordering by multiple fields via EF is chaining `OrderBy` with following 1..n `ThenBy` calls, so possibly more clear way would be to change `GetEmployeesAsync` to accept `params` expressions as parameter and process them accordingly. Something like this:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeesAsync(Expression<Func<Employee, object>> orderBy, params Expression<Func<Employee, object>>[] thenBys)
{
    IQueryable<Employee> query = ...;
    var orderedQuery = query.OrderBy(orderBy);
    for (int i = 0; i < thenBys.Length; i++)
    {
        orderedQuery = orderedQuery.ThenBy(thenBys[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

And usage looking like this:

```
 _service.GetEmployeesAsync(x => x.SomeProp, x=> x.SomeOtherProp)
```